# Mongodb check of there is any result of array A contains but array B do not

Tags: arrays, mongodb, database

here is my data structure
I want to get a result where I can get the document where there is a row in moderators but not in members

```
{
  "_id" : "10",
  "members" : [ 
    "10",
    "20",
    "30"
  ],
  "moderators" : [ 
    "50",
    "60",
    "70"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you paste a sample document here?

Comment: {
  "_id" : "10",
  "members" : [ 
    "10",
    "20",
    "30"
  ],
  "moderators" : [ 
    "50",
    "60",
    "70"
  ]
}

Comment: do you mean if 50 is in moderator and not in members? or moderator is non -zero sized array and members is an empty array?

Comment: You can use [setDifference](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/)

Comment: I mean return the document becouse there is 50 in moderators but nort in members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `$setDifference` to perform the relative complement to get rows in the `moderator` array which are not in `members` array followed by `$match` to get all the entries where there `foundInModerator` is populated.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
   [
     { $project: { members: 1, moderators: 1, foundInModerator: { $setDifference: [ "$moderators", "$members" ] }, _id: 0 } },
     { $match:{foundInModerator:{$ne:[] } } }
   ]
)
```

Comment: also how to add a condition where moderator array is not empty ?

Comment: You can do it in couple of ways. Use a `$match` stage at the top of the pipeline with condition on moderator array is not empty or you can update the `foundInModerator` expression to use `$cond` operator  with condition on moderator array is not empty; `if` false return `[]` array or `else` true return compare with  `setDifference`

Answer (score 0):

For returning the result where the value is in "one array" but "not in the other" simply use the [`$ne`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/ne/) operation:

```js
db.collection.find({ "moderators": "50", "members": { "$ne": "50" } })
```

So the match condition only returns positive where `"50"` is present in the `"moderators"` array but **not** in the `"members"` array.